# Include one RSS feed in another, possible? How?

Tags: rss

I'm using [JAlbum](http://jalbum.net) to create my webalbum and since version 8.1 JAlbum supports RSS feeds of the albums. However the RSS feeds generated by JAlbum do not work for albums containing a hierarchy of folders. What they try to do in the RSS feeds is to include the RSS feeds of the subfolders by including a  element (see example below). This does not work in NetNewsWire and GoogleReader and feedvalidator.org also reports warnings on this. It is possible to change the RSS template used by JAlbum to generate the RSS feed. I'm trying to fix this (and other) problems, but really doubt if it is possible at all to refer from one RSS feed to another and have the entries of the sub feed be included in the main feed.

- Is it possible to included RSS feeds in another feed? How? (Could not find examples and did not get responses on the JAlbum forum yet.)

If it's not possible I'll take another approach, but it feel quite nice if it would be possible to create a feed per folder and have the parent folder include the feeds of the subfolders by simply referring to it.

```
<channel>
    <title>test</title>
    <link>.</link>
    <generator>Jalbum 8.1</generator>
            <description></description>

    <jalbum:link rel="sub" href="aaa/album.rss" />                  

</channel>
```

Regards,
Gero

Answer (score 2):

You can probably achieve what you are looking for using [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/).  It has facilities for manipulating and combining feeds.  With a bit of trial and error you can do some pretty sophisticated things with it.

Comment: I'm sure I can create something used Yahoo Pipes. But the question remains is RSS (or ATOM) by itself has support for inclusion of other RSS files...

Gero